# Remove leading and trailing zeros from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

This functions and gives the desired result:

```
{1, 0, 2, 0, 0} /. {x___, 0 ...} :> {x}
```

> {1, 0, 2}

But with leading zeros it doesn't:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 2} /. {0 ..., x___} :> {x}
```

> {0, 0, 1, 0, 2}

Why is that so? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the docs of `Longest`:

> The default is to have earlier patterns match shortest sequences

Therefore, use `Longest` for the zeros:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 2} /. {Longest[0 ...], x___} :> {x}
```

> {1, 0, 2}

Comment: Or `{0, 0, 1, 0, 2} /. {0 ..., Shortest[x___]} :> {x}`

Answer (score 3):

Considering the efficiency,I will not use *Pattern Match*,this recommand a function `` Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros ``,which is intend to delete those zeros in tail.As your case:

```
Reverse[Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros[Reverse[{0, 0, 1, 0, 2}]]]
```

> {1, 0, 2}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0, 0, 1, 0, 2};

Flatten @ Rest @ Split @ Prepend[0] @ list
```

{1, 0, 2}

```
list = {1, 0, 2};

Flatten @ Rest @ Split @ Prepend[0] @ list
```

{1, 0, 2}

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice command for images that crops around the borders of an image using ImageCrop. You can use this in a slightly roundabout way by transforming the list into an image, applying ImageCrop, and then turning back into a list.

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0};
z = ConstantArray[0, Length[list] + 2];
Flatten[ImageData[ImageCrop[Image[{z, Flatten[{0, list, 0}], z}]]]]

{1., 0., 2.}
```

If you require integers, you could then Round to get

```
{1, 0, 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Split` and `Cases`:

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0};

Cases[s : {_} :> Sequence @@ s]@Split[list]

(*{1, 0, 2}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, s : {x_, __, y_} /; x != 0 && y != 0 :> Splice@s]

(*{1, 0, 2}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
trimZeros = Nest[Reverse @* Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros, #, 2] &;

trimZeros @ {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0}
```

> ```
> {1, 0, 2}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

a slight modification of the accepted answer:

```
{0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0} /. {Longest[0 ...], x___, 0 ...} :> {x} (* works with both leading and trailing zeros *)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also `DropWhile` and `DropTrailingWhile` in the WFR:
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DropWhile/
https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DropTrailingWhile
which can be used to do this:

```
ResourceFunction["DropWhile"][{0, 0, 1, 0, 2}, EqualTo[0]]
{1, 0, 2}
```

would remove 0s from the front. Or removing it from the back:

```
ResourceFunction["DropTrailingWhile"][{0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0}, EqualTo[0]]
{0, 0, 1, 0, 2}
```

Comment: You should consider writing a proper answer. In the way you have written, it appears as a comment.

Comment: I understand that you are the author of the resource function, but maybe it would be nice if you put the solution using the function you developed. What I see is that your function can be used in the same way that @kglr does by combining Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros with Nest and Reverse.

Comment: @SHuisman (+1) Thanks for adding your solution.